# Setting coordinate system for OSM performance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

For New Zealand OSM is a fantastic basemap for QGIS [https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)
But sometimes performance suffers I believe when the OSM layer tries to reproject on the fly. (Removing the OSM layer solves the performance problem)

OSM base maps are natively ESPG:3857 - WGS 84/ Pseudo-Mercator
The preferred projection for NZ is NZTM - NZ Transverse Mercator.

The question then is should set the global coordinate system to WGS 84 so that OSM performs the best then have other vector layers reproject on the fly - or is there a way to use OSM better i.e. convert to NZTM - is this the Warp (reproject) tool in QGIS?